# MVC WebApi Ajax error somente em servidor de homologação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Eu tenho uma pagina em mvc que chama um método no webapi (outro projeto dentro da solução), acontece que no localhost tudo funciona normalmente, quando vai homologação, ao chamar o método no api, ele excuta tudo corretamente, faz o que tem que fazer, porem o retorno do ajax vem como error, apenas como msg de error ( mesmo fazendo o que tem pra fazer)
Alguém pode me ajudar?
obs: Lembrando que o método funcionada no localhost, apenas no servidor de homologação esta dando erro ( erro, porem mesmo com erro executa o método )
chamada ajax:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Método no api:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o erro retornado?

Comment: Quando olhei o retorno do error: apenas o xhr é preenchido com o texto "error" e nada mais, fiz o teste rodando a aplicação localhost e apontando para o api que esta no servidor de homologação

Comment: Já tentou usar uma ferramenta REST que dispare essa requisição pra você e te retorne um erro mais completo?

Comment: Dica: poste código ao invés de *imagens* de código. Se por acaso, alguém tiver que reproduzir o erro, não vai poder...

Comment: Vou postar o código me desculpe,é que achei que ficava visualmente melhor rsrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o problema, acontece que no localhost ,o domínio ficava igual para o projeto webApi e para o WebSite, quando eu publiquei em homologação o domínio ficava diferente causando o problema do retorno do ajax, acabei deixando o webApi junto ao projeto do website, ao publicar o domínio ficou igual para ambos não ocorrendo o erro no ajax,
Obrigado pela ajuda galera.

Comment: Marque a sua resposta como respondido.